# Telegram bot responds in groups but not channels

Tags: javascript, telegram, node-telegram-bot-api

I'm making a bot and need to let the user save the channelID to an array.
The rest of the code is fine and works as intended in a group, but it's totally unresponsive inside a channel.

I've if else statements for if the chat is a channel, group, supergroup or private to no avail.

I'm using the node-telegram-bot-api - here is the snippet:

```
bot.onText(/\/getid/, (msg) => {
    console.log(`Channel/Group ID is: ${msg.chat.id}`);
});
```

Comment: Hi! Can you post some more of the code, like how and when `bot` is instantiated and where this handler is bound, in relation? If you log nothing for match-all (e.g., `/[\s\S]*/`) then the event handler is not bound.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
bot.on('channel_post', (msg) => {
    if (msg.text === "/getid") {
        console.log(`Channel ID is: ${msg.chat.id}`);
    }
});
```

I managed to solve with this.

Comment: Life's about helping others, right! :)  
I've set an alarm so I can come and approve later.